# Create empty json array with jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I have the following code:

```cpp
void MyClass::myMethod(Json::Value& jsonValue_ref)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= m_stringList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (m_boolMarkerList[i])
        {
            jsonValue_ref.append(stringList[i]);
        }
    }
}

void MyClass::myOuterMethod()
{
    Json::Value jsonRoot;
    Json::Value jsonValue;
    
    myMethod(jsonValue);

    jsonRoot["somevalue"] = jsonValue;
    Json::StyledWriter writer;
    std::string out_string = writer.write(jsonRoot);
}
```

If all markers in `m_boolMarkerList` are false, the `out_string` is `{ "somevalue" : null }`, but I want it to be an empty array: `{ "somevalue" : [ ] }`

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here are two ways you can do it:

```
jsonRootValue["emptyArray"] = Json::Value(Json::arrayValue);
// or 
jsonRootValue["emptyArray"] = Json::arrayValue;
```

Comment: why not just `jsonRootValue["emptyArray"] = Json::arrayValue`;

Comment: I think maybe when I posted this question - two years before your comment - that was just not possible.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by defining the Value object as an "Array object" (by default it makes it as an "object" object which is why your member becomes "null" when no assignment made, instead of [] )

So, switch this line:

```
 Json::Value jsonValue;
 myMethod(jsonValue);
```

with this:

```
Json::Value jsonValue(Json::arrayValue);
myMethod(jsonValue);
```

And voila! Note that you can change "arrayValue" to any type you want (object, string, array, int etc.) to make an object of that type. As I said before, the default one is "object".

Comment: Thank you Ahmet but this is exactly the same as user609441 already stated with a little more text.

Comment: Wanted to explain the reasons as well ^_^

Answer (score 5):

OK I got it. It is a little bit annoying but it is quite easy after all.
To create an empty json array with jsoncpp:

```
Json::Value jsonArray;
jsonArray.append(Json::Value::null);
jsonArray.clear();
jsonRootValue["emptyArray"] = jsonArray;
```

Output via writer will be:

```
{ "emptyArray" = [] }
```